# TYPO3 v8.7. - Language switch not working properly for detail records of own extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

How can it be that during a language change there is the phenomenon that with every other record that is selected ... the translated record of the first selected record is used?

So in concrete terms ... I have a larger number of records in my own extension. If I click on a record starting from the list view to get to the detail page ... I get the record displayed correctly:

```
domain/abc/abc/?tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=950007&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=abc
```

If I make the language switch I also get the right language selection for this record:

```
domain/de/abc/abc/?tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=950007&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=abc
```

But when I choose another record after that:

```
domain/abc/abc/?tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=950019&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=abc
```

I get a language switch to the very first record I selected:

```
domain/de/abc/abc/?tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=950007&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=abc
```

... and so on:

```
domain/abc/abc/?tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=950023&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=abc
domain/de/abc/abc/?tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=950007&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=abc
```

If I delete the FE cache in the BE ... the first selection works again ... but then the same phenomenon appears to the following.

I disabled RealUrl. It is a v8.7.19. I also deactivated cHash for this extension and it should stay deactivated. Someone an idea what to look for? Thank you very much. I use this typoscript to build the language switch:

```
lib.languageMenu = COA
lib.languageMenu {
    wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right languageMenu">|</li></ul></ul>
    20 = TEXT
    20.value = <img src="/fileadmin/templates/icons/icon_globe.png">
    20.wrap = <li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">&nbsp;|&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-language">
    30 = HMENU
    30 {
        special = language
        special.value = 0,1
        special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0
        addQueryString = 1
        addQueryString.exclude = L,id,cHash,no_cache
        addQueryString.method = GET
        useCacheHash = 1
        no_cache = 0        
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            noBlur = 1
            NO = 1
            NO {
                wrap = <ul>|</ul>
                linkWrap = <li>|</li>
                stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
                stdWrap.cObject.value = <img src="fileadmin/templates/icons/flags/us.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;English || <img src="fileadmin/templates/icons/flags/de.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Deutsch              
            }
            #CUR < .NO
            #CUR.doNotShowLink = 1
            ACT < .NO
            ACT.linkWrap = <li class="active">|</li>
            ACT.doNotShowLink = 1
            USERDEF1 < .NO
            USERDEF2 < .ACT
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a caching issue i guess your plugin does not generate the correct cHash for translateted pages thus only on version of the page is cached

Comment: Where can I check this or what exactly do I need to do?

Comment: ... I also deactivated cHash for this extension and I want to let it stay deactivated